# Apply the security policy for applet

Tags: java, security, applet

I have written one applet file to read the text file from local machine. I have embedded that applet into HTML file.  While running the HTML file the error shows like:

```
access denied (java.io.FilePermission d:\test.txt)
```

Then I have written one policy file and place in the `jre/lib/security/`. 
Now also it shows the same error.  Should I register that applet with policy file, or do I need to do any other steps?  Please explain clearly how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I register that applet with policy file,..

No.

> .. or do I need to do any other steps?

Instead of doing the stuff using policy files, digitally sign the applet.  It is the only practical way to get permissions to access a `File` for an applet deployed over the internet.  (And if it is not deployed from a web page, the question would be 'So why is it an applet?')  See [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) for more details.

Of course, if you can deploy in a Plug-In 2 JRE, the applet can be sand-boxed and the user can still open resources from the local file system.